# API call with angularJS and Rotten Tomato

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rotten-tomatoes

Right now I am just trying to get the API call to work, nothing fancy. In the end I will only want some basic info like name, runtime, rating and description... but that is all later. I can't even get the API call to work.

I have done several tutorials and I seem to be missing something.

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Watch a movie!</title>

<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/movies.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">NOW PLAYING</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">COMING FRIDAY</button>

<!-- PLACEHOLDER -->
<div id="movieInfoBox">
<div ng-controller = "movieController">{{movies}}</div>
</div>

</div> <!-- END WRAPPER -->
```

JS

```
var movies = angular.module("movies", []); //quotes are name of this file
movies.controller("movieController", function ($scope, $http){ //quotes are name of function called in index

     $http.jsonp("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/155655062.json?apikey=wq98h8vn4nfnuc3rt2293vru")

     .sucess(function(data)
          {$scope.movies = data;})
     .error(function(data){});
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include the JSON_CALLBACK in the URL. Otherwise the API returns JSON instead of JSONP. In the code below I use a config object instead of the parameters directly in the query string. It's just because it's easier to read, you can also use your version and add &callback=JSON_CALLBACK to the URL. See 'jsonp' [in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/fM7jb/

Code in the controller:

```
$http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/155655062.json', {
    params: {
        apikey: 'wq98h8vn4nfnuc3rt2293vru',
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }
})
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.movies = data;
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you. I had been experimenting with callback but it was always at the end of the url. I like how you put it in the param. not only did it work but it was easier to read.